# Get PocketC File Handle Int?

Tags: file-io, windows-ce, int, pocketc

I'm now taking a look at the [PocketC](http://orbworks.com/pcce/index.html) powerful tool, but there is an `fileopen` function, that generates a integer called `filehandle`, that is used for most of the File I/O operations of PocketC. How do I use this `int filehandle` to call the other file manipulation functions?

Here is my example function that I'm using at my program:

```
fileopen("\test.txt", 0, 0x00000000);
```

Description of `int filehandle`: Integer used for file operations, used as a pointer to the `fileopen` instruction.

Comment: For those not familiar with `PocketC`, can you post a link to the definition of the `fileopen` function?

Comment: Also, I did not vote down, but the question is not exactly clear in my opinion as well.

Comment: @Shaidi: `fileopen` opens files to be used. Sorry but I don't have the link for it's definition. :(

Comment: I still don't know why this 2 downvotes... **:-/**

Comment: @Nathan, the downvotes are probably because many people are having trouble understanding your question.  The problem, I think, is that they do not understand what you mean by "discover the `int filehandle`".  Print the value?  Save it to a variable?  (Apparently not since Joe's answer was not what you wanted).

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for your help, but see my comment after yours at Joe's post. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan, I've edited your question based on that comment.  Please make sure it accurately reflects what you're trying to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean discover the `int filehandle`? Your question is very vague.

Do you mean you want this?

```
int filehandle;
filehandle=fileopen("\test.txt", 0, 0x00000000); //PocketC may not like inline declarations.
```

Comment: @Nathan won't work as in how? Runtime error or compiler error? What's the error message?

Comment: I got this Compiler Error: `Variable int values must be const values, ex: int x = 5; int y = 7;`

Comment: @Nathan ok, now I'm stumped. This is now clearly a PocketC specific question, so I untagged C. I edited my question in a last attempt of fixing it though

Comment: @Nathan, post some code for where you do the assignment of the return value.  Are you attempting to declare the variable and assign it in the same action?  That might not be allowed based on the crappy documentation.  It would help if you were using a modern language that's actually supported.

Comment: @Joe, I'm not even sure if it qualifies as documentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `fileopen` on success will be different each time -- that's the point of returning a handle, to uniquely identify a resource.  If it returned the same value each time, you would have no way to distinguish the different files you had opened.

You need to save the value like Earlz suggested and then pass the saved variable to the other file manipulation functions.

Comment: @Earlz: See my comment on your post.

Comment: oh I wasn't aware nathan made it a CW question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.orbworks.com/wince/doc/api.html), `fileopen` RETURNS the filehandle as an int.

```
fileopen(string filepath, int type, int flag) :  open a file in unicode/ascii. 
You can create a new file or simply open one. Please use the flag correctly.

...

Return: Returns an integer as the File Handle if successful,otherwise -1, 
Remember to keep this handle value somewhere, 
Because you have to use this handle for the rest of file operations.
```

Comment: I know this, but I want to know which integer(the number that it's stored) is this! To know what to type on the other file operations functions. Also, I already knew this, because I have the docs here on my computer!

Comment: @Nathan, you need to clarify your question.  Are you asking how to pass this returned `filehandle` to the other file operation functions?

Comment: Yeah, I need to know which number it will return if it works(not fail and return -1).

Comment: @Nathan. I think you are misunderstanding how filehandles work. They aren't a number you can just memorize. They are like memory addresses. They change every time you run it.